# Как сделать переключатель CSS классов функцией?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть блок `gallery`, в нем секция c ссылками `gallery_nav_link` и секция со статьями `gallery_article`.

При помощи следующего кода клик по ссылке отображает соответствующую ей статью – своего рода слайдер:

```
(function() {
  //получаем ссылки и статьи в массивы
  var galery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
  var links = galery.querySelectorAll('.gallery_nav_link');
  var articles = galery.querySelectorAll('.gallery_article');
  //вспомогательные функции добавления и удаления классов
  function rmClass(elem, itemClass) {
    elem.classList.remove(itemClass);
  }
  function addClass(elem, itemClass){
    elem.classList.add(itemClass);
  }

  function show(arrLinks, arrArticle) {
    arrLinks = [].slice.apply(arrLinks);//вот здесь не совсем понятно,по сути у нас и так массив, но без копирования не работает  forEach?
    //получаем индекс ссылки в массиве по которой кликнули
    arrLinks.forEach(function (element, i, arrLinks) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       //завершаем работу если у статьи с этим индексом есть класс gallery_article--show
       if(arrArticle[i].classList.contains('gallery_article--show')) {
           return;
       }
       else{
          //ищем в цикле элемент с этим классом
          for (var j = 0; j < arrArticle.length; j++){
            var index = arrArticle[j]  
            if(index.classList.contains('gallery_article--show')){
               rmClass(index, 'gallery_article--show');//удаляем класс
               addClass(index, 'gallery_article--zoom-out');//добавляем анимацию
               setTimeout(rmClass, 500, index, 'gallery_article--zoom-out');//удаляем анимацию
            }
        } 
         //добавляем класс статье с индексом соответсвующем индексу кликнутой ссылке
         addClass(arrArticle[i], 'gallery_article--show');
       }

     })
   });
  }

  show(links,articles);

})();
```

Хотелось бы усовершенствовать функцию для работы с *разными* классами и блоками, подобными `gallery` путём передачи аргументов.

Получить возможность, если это будет необходимо, обрабатывать несколько анимаций. Сделать её универсальной насколько возможно.

Comment: А вы бы не могли упростить пример? Выделить ту часть, которая у вас вызывает затруднения. Большинство задач можно абстрагировать до пары строк. Вряд ли кому то охото читать эти горы кода.

Comment: непонятно как вы хотите в итоге использовать и с каким другим блоком?

Comment: @Vladimir Morulus да горы строк читать и не нужно... они лишь для того, чтобы показать работающий пример....  
вопрос по коду java script  Как можно оптимизировать функцию show для многократного применения на различных блоках.... 
А ситуацию с многократным нажатием одной и той же ссылки я решил сделав проверку на наличие класса у нужного элемента.

Comment: @ Grundy как видно, сейчас функция работает с двумя массивами - массивами ссылок и массивами статей, возвращая индекс элемента в массиве по клику на ссылку и присваивая элементу соответствующего индекса в массиве статей определенные классы.  
Код функции завязан на этих классах....что плохо (имхо), так как при добавлении (допустим) еще одного блока с таким же функционалом придется дублировать код еще оаз..... Я же хочу  классы и массивы с которыми работает функция сделать передаваемыми параметрами....

Comment: так, и что мешает сделать их параметрами?

Comment: нехватка знаний как лучше организовать такой код...

Comment: Я бы вам ответил как оптимизировать функцию show, если бы такая существовала, но поскольку вы ее написали сами, суть вашего вопроса сводится к просьбе изучить ваш тяжелый код с целью понять вообще о чем идет речь. Потому что такого понятия как параметры в синтаксисе Javascript опять таки не существует. Есть аргументы функций, есть свойства объекта, есть аттрибуты тэгов. Разобраться что вам нужно без перечитывания всего вашего кода просто нереально. Поэтому я и предложил написать более компактный пример по сути.

Comment: @VladimirMorulus, аргументы функций = параметры функций

Comment: @VladimirMorulus, обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас весь код неоправданно громоздкий. Во-первых, для реализации такой задачи лучше подойдет jQuery. У него есть и быстрый подсчет позиции элемента, и перебором элементов и код вашей функции на нем будет выглядеть компактней.
Примерно так:

```
 $("a").click(function() {
    $("a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("article").hide();
    $("div>article").eq($(this).index()).show();
    return false;
 });
```

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/Morulus/xra9pozn/

Но даже без jQuery он так же будет достаточно компактным

```
(function(query) {
  let alla = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(query));
  alla.forEach(function(a, index) {
    a.addEventListener('click', function(index) {
        alla.forEach(function(a) { a.classList.remove("current"); });
      this.classList.add('current');
      document.querySelector('article.visible').classList.remove('visible');
      document.querySelectorAll('article')[index].classList.add('visible');
    }.bind(a, index));
  });
 })('a');
```

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/Morulus/sorko2se/

Но здесь в корне не верный подход из-за того, что не стоит выбирать элементы по их индексам. Гораздо проще на этапе верстки назначить каждой статье уникальный id и далее делать выборку по id, а не по индексу.

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/Morulus/0bwLnct7/

А можно пойти по пути MVC и реализовать например на Angular:
https://jsfiddle.net/Morulus/1g45tqpx/

Но самым лучшим способом было бы использование ajax для подгрузки контента артикла на лету и не связываясь с show/hide в принципе. Тогда бы код был самым компактным:

```
$("a[ref]").click(function() { 
  $("article").load("ajax/"+$(this).attr("rel")+".html"); 
});
```

Ну вот как то так, надеюсь это даст вам пищу для размышлений.